# Matlab - how to read 2 bytes at a time

Tags: matlab

I have a number like this - 778310098 - and I want to read 2 bytes at a time. So, I am expecting my output to be 77; 83; 10; 09; 8. I tried using the below:
uint16(fread(fileID,inf, 'ubit8')) and the output I get is the ASCII value of the individual numbers:
     55
     55
     56
     51
     49
     48
     48
     57
     56

What do I need to do to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to convert it to a string, then process the string, then convert it back to an integer. While this may not be particularly elegant or perfect, will this do the trick?

```
a = 778310098;
b = num2str(a);

for i = 1:2:length(b)
    if i == length(b)                 % to handle the case for odd input
        split = str2num(b(i))
    else
        split = str2num(b(i:i+1))     % handle all others
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes, this did do the trick. Thanks. I will try some more scenarios. But I believe this will work.

Comment: I figured out a really clever way to do this using recursion to split it by using `floor` and `rem`, unfortunately that would require you to write your own class or something to keep the heading zeros :(

Answer (score 3):

To read pairs of ASCII digits from a text file (we tend not to describe text files in byets, but in characters), use:

```
[10 1] * (fread(fileID,[2 inf], 'char') - 48)
```

To read bytes pairwise from a binary file, try

```
fread(fileID,inf, '*uint16')
```

Comment: Thanks. But the output I get is like this:  fread(fileID,inf, '*uint16')

ans =

  14135
  13112
  12337
  14640 . A combination of the ascii values of the 2 bytes.

Comment: Just an observation. Surrounding the fread by char like this - char(fread(fileID,inf, '*ubit8')) - gives me the individual numbers:
7
7
8
3
1
0
0
9
8

Comment: @Sarvavyapi... it was not at all clear from the question that you are reading from a text file.