# How to write a one liner that converts string array input into cell array and appends additional cell array term?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

Inspired by this question:

[Matlab - how to read 2 bytes at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893348/matlab-how-to-read-2-bytes-at-a-time)

Defining

```
s= '778310098';
```

I wrote a one-liner:

```
c = reshape(reshape(s(1:2^(nextpow2(length(s))-mod(length(s),2))),2,[]).',[],2)
```

which outputs

```
c =

77
83
10
09
```

and takes me far, but no cigar, since my objective was to have the result as a `cell array` of strings, including the odd terminal element `'8'`.

I'm wondering how I could, as concisely as possible, turn the contents of the ouput `char array` into a `cell array` with entries

```
d{1} = '77'
d{2} = '83'
d{3} = '10'
d{4} = '09'
```

Also, I'd like to append the missing value (concisely), such that

```
d{5} = '8'
```

Comment: No comments on crazy (and incorrect) use of `nextpow2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly for the odd case:

```
mat2cell(s, 1, [2*ones(floor(size(s, 2)/2)), mod(size(s,2), 2)])'
```

but in the even case it will add an extra empty cell at the end. I suggest you just don't enforce a one-liner rule on yourself in this case.

Comment: ok, the following amended answer worked very nicely - `mat2cell(s, 1, [2*ones(1,floor(size(s, 2)/2)), mod(size(s,2), 2)])'` Good job... check mark but no uptick for you :>)

Comment: @TryHard yes sorry that was just a typo